# .NET core 3.1 ApplicationInsight IntrumentKey null

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, blazor-server-side

In .net core 3.1 Blazor App, my Instrument Key is always null.
I added the follwing package

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 2.14.0-beta5
```

in startup.cs, i am adding the following line

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

i even tried hardcoding the instrument key via options but no luck there either.

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions aiOptions
              = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();

            aiOptions.InstrumentationKey = Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey").Value;
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options);
```

in appsetting.json, i have defined the applicaiton Insight

```
 "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "XXXXXXX-4f59-4580-a96a-XXXXXXX"
  }
```

In my Blazor Page i am inject the dependency

```
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
```

now when i search for  `telemetryClient.InstrumentationKey`  it is empty.

What am i missing ?

Comment: You could try to specify the key as APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY environment variable, although both options should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird. I tried to view the key by calling telemetryClient.InstrumentationKey as well, but like you said it's empty. But when I try to track something with .TrackEvent, it logs.

For example;

```
_telemetryClient.TrackEvent("BlazorAppSampleEvent", new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "Hello from", "Blazor App" } });
```

[image: App Insight Live Sample]

Sounds interesting to me, I will have a couple of minutes more and update here if I get something new.

BTW, just so you know, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 2.14.0 is publicly available, so you can upgrade it from beta-5 to public one.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/2.14.0/

[image: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 2.14.0]

Comment: I am using Blazor Server side ASP.net 3.1, i don't get any telemetry, for now i have hard coded value in my index page, it retains the key when i access on other page.
Interesting hard coding the key in Startup does not work.

Comment: I use the same for testing this - I just created Application Insights from Azure portal :) Have you tried upgrading your package?

Answer (score 0):

This is an [old issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/141#issuecomment-197623921).

`TelemetryClient.InstrumentationKey` or `TelemetryClient.Context.InstrumentationKey` should be empty unless you explicitly set it there as an override of what is in configuration.

As mentioned above, explicitly set it like: `TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient() { InstrumentationKey= "your_ikey" };`, then you can see the key via `TelemetryClient.InstrumentationKey` or `TelemetryClient.Context.InstrumentationKey`.

Note: this issue does not break the functionality of application insights.